# WinJS SQLite runAsync all before doing something else

Tags: sqlite, winjs, promise

I have a collection of INSERT statements that gets run within a SQLite async method:

```
SQLite3JS.openAsync(path).then(function (db) {
    $.each(sql, function (idx, item) {
        return db.runAsync(item).done(function complete(xhr) {
            var i = 0;
        });
    });
});
```

I want the collection to be inserted, then do something after this has completed successfully. I tried to follow through on `then()` promises, but they all get called before the `db.runAsync()` gets fired.

Is there a clean way to do this? Basically, I have a progress ring that should be removed once all this has completed, but I cannot get this to fire correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to use `WinJS`'s ability to [join multiple promises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211774.aspx) together...

```
SQLite3JS.openAsync(path).then(function (db) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(sql, function (idx, item) {
        promises.push( db.runAsync(item) );
    });

    return WinJS.Promis.join( promises ).then(
        function success() {
            // all done!
        },
        function error() {
            // something didn't work
        },
    );
});
```

Comment: i tried, but I did it wrong according to your example, thank you. i'll try this and feed back.

Comment: thanks. it works perfectly. i just had to promise on the correct calls