# How to execute an action after a for loop with asynchronous actions WinJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, winjs

I have this block of code on WinJS:

```
// Triggers SOAP requests depending of how many webServices are required for uploading all the pictures
for (var i = 0; i < arrayCaptures.length; i++) 
{
    callWS(arrayTextFieldValues[i], UID_KEY[7], arrayCaptures[i].name).then(function (response) 
    {
        if (response == true) 
        {
            //if true, we have store the id of the picture to delete
            deletedCapturesIndexesArray.push(i);
        }
    },
    function (error) { }
    );
}

//my next action comes after this for loop
removeCapturesOfScreenWithIndexArray(deletedCapturesIndexesArray);
```

What it does: it executes a block of code with an asyncronous actions (SOAP WebService calls) and in a second thread it executes removeCapturesOfScreenWithIndexArray,

And what I need is this program executing my next action (removeCapturesOfScreenWithIndexArray) only when all of my actions inside the for loop are finished, I think it has to do with promises topic but I don't have this clear, how to do that???

Comment: I need to wait for all the promises to be fullfilled for executing my next line of code  removeCapturesOfScreenWithIndexArray(deletedCapturesIndexesArray); but my current code skips to the next step, how to force it to wait till for all the promises??? could you please help me with an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinJS SQLite runAsync all before doing something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803684/winjs-sqlite-runasync-all-before-doing-something-else) (FYI, I appreciate that you are new to WinJS and trying to figure out some tricky things, but please do some searching on google, SO, or MSDN before posting new questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something to happen after a promise completes, you need to attach to the promise's `then`. If you want something to happen after several promises all complete, you can join the promises into a single combo-promise, and then attach to the `then` of the combo-promise.

Your code also has a bug wherein it captures the loop variable. This means that `deleteCapturesIndexArray.push(i)` will always push `arrayCaptures.length`.

Here's a fix for both problems.

```
// Triggers SOAP requests depending of how many webServices are required for uploading all the pictures
var promiseArray = arrayCaptures.map(function(capture, i) {
    return callWS(arrayTextFieldValues[i], UID_KEY[7], capture.name).then(function (response) 
    {
        if (response == true) 
        {
            //if true, we have store the id of the picture to delete
            deletedCapturesIndexesArray.push(i);
        }
    },
    function (error) { }
    );
});

// Run some more code after all the promises complete.
WinJS.Promise.join(promiseArray).then(function() {
    removeCapturesOfScreenWithIndexArray(deletedCapturesIndexesArray);
});
```